# Better code structure for spam filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a spam filter for a client that rejects submission of forms containing http in a specific field (input).

I am now trying to adapt that for a site which has many forms but also different ID's for each input which are required by other functions.

How should I re-write this code so it applies on any input in a form regardless of field ID?

**Html**

```
<form action="#" name="form">
<input type="text" name="txt" id="txt" onblur="validate('txt');"/>
<p id="alert1" style="display:none;"> Please remove the link from this field to   continue with the form submission. </p>
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="joso"/>
<input type="submit" id="submit"/>
<p id="alert2" style="display:none;"> Please remove the link from this comments area to continue with the form submission </p>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function validate(id) {
    var txtbox = document.getElementById('txt');
    var txtvalue = txtbox.value;
    txtindex = txtvalue.indexOf('http');
    if (txtindex!=-1) {
        document.getElementById('alert1').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('alert1').style.display = 'none';
    }   
}
```

**Solution performance**

For those interested in the solution - it works very well, which is why I want to port it on all my other sites. It cut down 90% of the spam we were getting even though we had another capcha solution installed and it increased the no. of valid requests for offers which we were losing because the capcha solution our CMS was offering were too hard to read. It also performs better than the capcha we were previously using.

Comment: What if the spammer doesn't execute the javascript?

Comment: Rewrite it in server side script.

Comment: A coding cat? No way..

Comment: actually, most of spam is thrown but bots not parsing any js. They use sockets.

Comment: it cut capcha by nearly 90% while not using any other spam filter such as capcha, etc. To date it has better performance than Recapcha. 

I cannot re-write server side because the platform I am using does not allow server-side scripting (business catalyst) and setting up node.js just for this is overkill

Comment: Another idea: create the form inputs dynamically in javascript when the page loads. The spam bots won't see the input fields because they are not in the html and they don't execute the javascript.